# java split () method with two delimiters

Tags: java

I have a string like

```
abababa:nsndnfnng.leleelld_kdjdh
```

I want to split it on ":" and ".", so that I get a list as follows:

```
{abababa, nsndnfnng, eleelld_kdjdh}
```

how can I do this with calling the split() once?

Comment: Just call the split() on the string 2 times, once on the original string, and then on the sub-strings generated from the first step.

Comment: looking for a better way. tnx any way.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for `String#split` method. Since it accepts regex which will describe delimiter your code could look like

```
String[] result = yourString.split("[:.]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`String.split("[:.]")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which takes a regex argument

**Common pitfall** If you would only want to split on `.` alone you have to escape the dot `String.split("\\.")` (or use a character class here too `String.split("[.]")`)

Comment: `:` and `.` are not special in character class. There is no need to escape them there.

Comment: "Note that the dot . *needs* to be escaped." that would be true if `.` would not be inside `[...]`. Most regex metacharacters have no special meaning in character class because its purpose is to represent single characters, which means we can even write `[+/:*()]` and it will represent single `+` `/` `:` `*` `(` or `)` characters. Same about `[.]`. You can find more info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special

Comment: You are right since they are within a *Character class*, did not think about that

Comment: If you agree that "Note that the dot . needs to be escaped" is not right (as `.` is placed in `[..]`) feel free to remove that part from your answer as it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

use regex and split the string

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String REGEX_PATTERN = "[:.\\_]";
    String s1 = "abababa:nsndnfnng.leleelld_kdjdh";
    String[] result = s1.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
    for (String myString : result) {
        System.out.println(myString);
    }
}
```